# Searching database mysql

Tags: php, sql

I created a stored procedure to search my database by name. I have many text files saved in database named like: a.txt, a1.txt,a2.txt,a3.txt,...

When i run my stoerd procedure only 1 resoult is showing.

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ('%', search ,'%');
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: your query looks ok.. show your stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

Your problem solution is

```
 SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ('%'. $search . '%');
```

or if you are using directly then on sql server then

```
SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name LIKE CONCAT ('%search%');
```

Comment: ty! and how can i combine searches if i want to check in name,comment, and by author. And the resoults are oredered like this. Name, comment, author

Answer (score 0):

If `$search` (note the dollar sign) is a PHP variable (I assume that because you tagged the question with "php"), you don't have to use the SQL function `CONCAT` but join the strings in PHP and send it all to MySQL:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name LIKE "%'.$search.'%"';
```

That's because `CONCAT` will make your `%` treated as a character, not a search criterion.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM cars WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' ;
```

or this

```
    WHERE name LIKE '$search'
```